# Showing numbers one after the other instead of them adding up

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
one = 1
two = 2
three = 3
result = (one + two + three)
print(result)
```

Instead of the result being `6` I want it to be `123` because I want it to show the three numbers one after the other and not have them add up.
If you have any idea how to solve this thanks in advance.

Comment: `print("{one}{two}{three}".format(one=one, two=two, three=three))`

Comment: @Nefrin: You would get a TypeError.  You can't concatenate strings and integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either

```
result = '%d%d%d' % (one, two, three)
```

Or

```
result = one * 100 + two * 10 + three
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
result = "{one}{two}{three}".format(one=one, two=two, three=three)
print(result) # yields "123"
```

You want an integer instead then `print(int(result))`

Demo:

```
>>> one = 1
>>> two = 2
>>> three = 3
>>> result = "{one}{two}{three}".format(one=one, two=two, three=three)
>>> result
'123'
>>> int(result)
123
```